# difference betwern require __DIR__ and __DIR__

Tags: yii, param

i a new yii developer and i do not understand one thing. In common/config/params.php file, i have following code:

```
<?php
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'supportEmail' => 'support@example.com',
    'user.passwordResetTokenExpire' => 3600,
    'regions' => require __DIR__ . '/region.php',
];
```

what is the difference between `'regions' => require __DIR__ . '/region.php'`, and `'regions' => __DIR__ . '/region.php',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `'regions' => __DIR__ . '/region.php'` **`regions`** will contain a string variable (path to region.php based on current dir)

In `'regions' => require __DIR__ . '/region.php'` **`regions`** will contain an object of `region.php` class